# How to postpone doPost method?

Tags: java, servlets

In my servlet, I upload a file to a specific url, then call a method in a different class to grab that file online and alter it.  The problem is that a lot of the time, there is a lot of data in the file and the dopost method finishes (and goes to the next page from the upload file submit form) before the file is fully altered.  How do I prevent the do post method from going to the next page before my file is completely altered?

I want the Test.preFirstMethod() to finish before the page reloads and makes the download link.  Test.preFirstMethod() takes in an excel file and modifies it using dynamic content from the internet.

```
public class Uploads extends HttpServlet {
private Object lock1 = new Object();
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private ServletFileUpload uploader = null;
public Thread tt = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
        try {Test.preFirstMethod();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

int BUFFER_LENGTH = 4096;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String fileName="";
    for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
        InputStream is = request.getPart(part.getName()).getInputStream();
        fileName = getFileName(part);
        File f2 = new File(fileName);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR") + "nn.xlsx");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = is.read(bytes, 0, BUFFER_LENGTH)) != -1) {
            os.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        os.flush();
        is.close();
        fileName=fileName.substring(0,fileName.lastIndexOf("."))+"_ZillowAdded.xlsx";
        try {
            tt.start();
            try { tt.join(); } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
            InputStream is2 = new FileInputStream(f2);
            FileOutputStream os2 = new FileOutputStream(System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR") + fileName);
            while ((read = is2.read(bytes, 0, BUFFER_LENGTH)) != -1) {
                os2.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            os2.flush();
            is2.close();
            os2.close();

        } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        os.close();
    }

    if(!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
        throw new ServletException("Content type is not multipart/form-data");
    }

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    out.write("<html><head></head><body>");
    out.write("File "+fileName.substring(0,fileName.indexOf("_Zillow"))+ " uploaded successfully.");
    out.write("<br>");
    out.write("<a href=\"/uploads/"+fileName+"\">Download "+fileName+"</a>");
    out.write("</body></html>"); }
```

Comment: You mean it times out? Seems like it should block unless you're making your upload async? You need to post some code.

Comment: Why are you using `Thread` at all? Why don't just call your `Test.preFirstMethod()` directly from `doPost()`?

Comment: I did that originally but then it just goes to the page with the html written in this code before the file that is uploaded is fully analyzed and modified

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. You want to ask how to run `Test.preFirstMethod()` synchronously instead of asynchronously. Well, the answer depends on its implementation which is nowhere covered in the question in its current form. Based on the symptoms, it's apparently spawning a separate thread and performing the job in there. The problem has got nothing to do with the client (the servlet in this case). Manually fiddling with `Thread` instances inside a Java EE application is also a big red alert. Never do that.